# Displaying non-linear set as linear set.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, graph-theory

I'm doing a project on graph theory and my problem is the following:

$K = \{\{x_0,x_1\},\{x_1,x_2\},\cdots,\{x_{n-1},x_n\}\}$

I now want to express, mathematically, the following:

"There exist an ordered list P, which contains all distinct elements of set K"

That is:

$P = (x_0,x_1,\cdots,x_{n-1},x_n)$

so P is not really a set, but rather an ordered list.

Example of what I'm trying to do would be:

$\require{cancel} \cancel{\forall K_i\in K:P \cup K_i|x_i\in K_i}$

Comment: The *elements* of $K$ are of the form $\{x_i,x_{i+1}\}$. The union $\bigcup K$ is the set containing the elements $x_0, x_1,\dots,x_n$.

Comment: Apart from the above, I find "There exist an ordered list $P$, which contains all distinct elements of set $K$ / $\bigcup K$" a pretty mathematical statement in itself. If it is more clear what you mean when you use words, why use symbols?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean by $K\cup K"$, but i guess you're right, it's already pretty well defined without symbols.

Comment: Ah, I see now. With $K$ / $\bigcup K$ in the second comment I meant elements of the set $K$ *or* elements of the set $\bigcup K$. The slash is an English slash denoting "or", not a mathematical one... It was meant as a correction to your sentence (since you should take $\bigcup K$, not $K$ to get the elements $x_i$). Sorry to be confusing.

Comment: $\bigcup$ is a very handy operation then :) Thank you for that, I'm sure this is could be used in the project.

One last thing, is it possible to go from an unordered set like $\bigcup K$ to an ordered set:

$\{x_0,x_1,\cdots , x_{n-1},x_n\}$ to $(x_0,x_1,\cdots , x_{n-1},x_n)$

Comment: Not without specifying *how* to order the unordered set. For example $\{x_n,x_{n-1},\dots,x_1,x_0\}$ is the same set as $\{x_0,\dots,x_n\}$: it is not ordered. So how do we know that we have to pick $x_0$ to be first, $x_1$ to be second, etc. in the ordered list? There are many different ordered lists that can be made with the elements from $\bigcup K$; to be exact, $(n+1)!$ many.

Comment: By the way, we usually call an *unordered set* just a *set*, and an *ordered list* just a *list* or *sequence* or *tuple*.

Comment: Yeah the problem about how to order the elements were the thing that had me confused. Thank you for your fast response, have a good day :)